# How do you describe only the name of the directory in computer science?

Tags: programming, computing

In computer science, I found the word "directory name" seems to describe path of the directory. (because when you use dirname command in linux you get path)

Then what word(s) do you use to describe only the name of the directory?

For example, if there is directories as follow,

`"C:\folder1\filename.xml"`

"folder1" is what I want to describe, not "C:\folder1"

Comment: The directory name usually just means the actual directory (or 'folder') , 'folder1' in your example. A 'path' contains more than one directory, maybe starting from the drive root or mount point, e.g. /mnt/archive/systemlogs/december/mon23/.

Comment: Computer Science SE (which has a terminology tag) is the more obvious fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two complimentary commands for parsing a pathname:

```
Path             Dirname       Basename
one/two/three    one/two       three
/a/b/c           /a/b          c
./x/y/           ./x           y
```

The `dirname` and `basename` commands were given their names early in UNIX history, so don't rely on their having any consistent naming convention.

Assuming that `three` and `c` are files and not directories, generally, one would say:

- File paths: `./one/two/three`, `/a/b/c`
- File names: `three` and `c`
- Directory names: `two`, `b`, and `x`
- Directory paths: `one/two`, `/a/b`, and `.`

The Directory names and paths could also be given a trailing `/` to make it more obvious that they aren't files.

So in your non-UNIX (`C:\folder1\filename.xml`) example, `filename.xml` would be the filename and `folder1` would be the directory name.

E.g. "`filename.xml` is a file in the `folder1` directory."